# Object doesn’t support this property or method – Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello guys I have a nice javascript project to take on.  Im starting off trying to toggle some javascript and Im getting an error here:

```
    function saveComment( id )
{
    $("#commentErrors").css("visibility", "hidden");

    var hashTab = {};
    commentField = document.getElementById("comments-"+id);

    // hard code the constant Node.TEXT_FIELD as its value "3" since
    // IE doesn't support DOM constants correctly
    hashTab["comments"] = commentField.firstChild.nodeType==3
                        ? commentField.innerHTML
                        : commentField.firstChild.value;



    hashTab["id"] = id;
    //hashTab["entryWorkloadYear"] = document.getElementById("entryWorkloadYear").value;  // Where is this element?!

  ----->>>      WhatIfDataAction.saveComment(hashTab,
            {
                callback:saveCommentCallback,
                timeout:60000,
                errorHandler: dwrSessionErrorHandler
            }
        );
}
```

any thoughts?

saveComment looks like this:

```
    public CommentForm saveComment(Map<String,String> properties)
throws Exception
{
EntryBean entry = WhatifCache.fetchEntryFromCache(getSession());
CommentForm form = new CommentForm(properties);
if (form.validate(this))
{
    CommentBean bean = entry.getComment(form.getId());

    bean = CommentBean.deepCopy(bean);

    form.overlayFormData(bean);

    entry.updateComment(bean);
}

return form;
```

}

Comment: Unlrelated, but var hashTab = {}; is an object, you want an array: var hashTab = [];

Comment: `saveComment` is evidently not a property of `WhatIfDataAction`. We can't see where `WhatIfDataAction` is defined or where its properties are populated, so we can't really tell you anything more useful than the error message.

Comment: @Diodeus Really? If `hashTab` was an array, how could he do things like `hashTab["id"] = id;`?

Comment: thanx for the feedback guys...Im checking it now

Comment: `saveComment` is not javascript! Looks like c# or java...

Comment: guys I had to add the method call in an xml file...sorry for the run around :)

Comment: Peter, go read: http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the WhatIfDataAction object does not have a method named saveComment.